# Solving inequality to state function f>1

Tags: inequality

I have the following function,

$$f = \frac{x-a}{y-a} $$

I want to specify the condition for $f>1$

I wrote it as, 
$$f>1$$ when 
$$\frac{x-a}{y-a}>1$$
so, I rewrote it as, 
$$x-a>y-a$$
and 
$$x>y$$

Now, can I write $f>1$ when $x>y$ ? 
I doubt because this is not always true. 
e.g. $a = 1$, $x = 1.1$ and $y = 0.9 $ results, $f = -1$ although $x>y$.

Can anybody help me to state it correctly? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to be careful when you are multiplying with negative numbers, sometimes $y-a<0$ then you must change from $>$ to $<$ when you are multiplying with $y-a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x,y;a)$ be given by

$$f(x,y;a)=\frac{x-a}{y-a}$$

If $f(x,y;a)>1$, then

$$\frac{x-a}{y-a}>1\implies \frac{x-a}{y-a}-1>0\implies\frac{x-y}{y-a}>0$$

from which we see that if $y>a$, then $x>y$ and if $y<a$, then $x<y$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have two queries. You wrote $f(x,y′a)$. Is it the same as $f(x,y;a)$ ? Also, what if I have to prove the same for $f<0$. Will it be, $f<0$ when $(x-a)*(y-a)<0$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And yes, there were two typos, which have been corrected now.